# myopenid.com email firstname lastname not available

Tags: openid

I am trying to setup a page from which users can login to my site using openid. While i successfully set up google and yahoo, myopenid is headache. It is not giving me user's email or fullname or lastname. I tried with both attribute exchange and SReg. No luck. Please someone guide me.

Comment: I'm running into a similar situation.  What platform or third party libraries are you using?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8328015/16584