# MyOpenId not sharing email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use MyOpenID for my sign-in, but it doesn't seem to be sharing the email address.

If I use Google or others I do seem to get the email address, though.  I thought that this was a standard field to return.

I even see some documentation here that seems to suggest they would share email:
https://rpxnow.com/docs/providers

(I'm using Ruby on Rails and Janrain for this project)

One interesting thing is that if I setup an identity page on MyOpenId, then the email ***IS*** shared with my application.  I thought that there was supposed to be a way when logging in with MyOpenID to specify what data is shared during "SimpleRegistration"?

Comment: Sorry, please disregard my vote to close. I misread the question the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was testing with my own MyOpenId account and the very *first* time I logged in to my development server I had not paid enough attention.

When logging in the first time it said something along the lines of "*blah* site is asking you to share information with it.  Click here to use an existing persona or to create a new one.  I didn't select one and it defaulted to "don't ask again".

I was able to fix this by going in to MyOpenId and revoking permission for my site.  Then the next time I logged in it asked me again and it worked.

Comment: I can see only one option that is "Skip this step next time I sign in to www.mysite.com". There's no "is asking you to share information" nor "don't ask again", as in this screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/8quzvxn3r/ Any idea?